Powershell - checking latest log file
I have the following PS script which scans a location which will have logs files added hourly, i would like the following script to scan the location and only work on teh most recent log file, can someone please help me identify what i need to add into teh script plase:
Hi all,
I got the following powereshell script that is scannign all present log files, but im trying to add a condition so it only checks the most recent, i know its a small thing just can get it to work
Any pointers would be great...
$logFilePath = '\\MyLogFiles\Files*.log'
$SearchString = 'TOTAL DATA ENTRY'
$outputFilePath = "C:\Reports\Results\Success $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"  
Select-String -Path $logFilePath -Pattern $searchString -SimpleMatch |
Set-Content $outputFilePath
$sendMailMessageSplat = @{
    To          = 'Joanne.Bloggs@Mail.com'
    From        = 'Joe.Bloggs@Mail.com'
    Subject     = "Weekly logs - $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
    Body        = 'See attached'
    Attachments = "C:\Reports\Results\Success $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"
    SmtpServer  = 'mail.server.com'
}
Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat


Use Get-ChildItem to discover the matching files, then use Sort-Object and Select-Object to only pick the most recent one:
$logFilePath = '\\MyLogFiles\Files*.log'
$SearchString = 'TOTAL DATA ENTRY'
$outputFilePath = "C:\Reports\Results\Success $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"  

# pick only the most recently created log file
$latestLogFile = Get-ChildItem $logFilePath |Sort-Object CreationTime |Select-Object -Last 1
$latestLogFile |Select-String -Pattern $searchString -SimpleMatch |...


As sirtao points out, in PowerShell 7 you can use Sort-Object ... -Descending -Top 1 to only get the last item in the sort order, after which you can remove Select-Object completely from the pipeline:
$latestLogFile = Get-ChildItem $logFilePath |Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending -Top 1


When using Powershell 7.x, it's possible to skip using Select-item by using only Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending -Top 1
